# How to generate phone number extensions in MS access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi I’m new in MS access programming. Please can you help me to know the MS access VBA code for generate the phone number extensions.

Example

**Table1 (Input)**

```
Phone_number_main,  Range_lower,    Range_upper  
9774308333,         1,              3  
977430866,          10,             14
```

**Table2 (output)**

```
Phone_number_main,  Phone_number_extention  
9774308333,         97743083331  
9774308333,         97743083332  
9774308333,         97743083333  
977430866,          97743086610  
977430866,          97743086611  
977430866,          97743086612  
977430866,          97743086613  
977430866,          97743086614
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [POST Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: I have not idea what you're asking. It appears you're looking for a simple loop that adds an increasing number (converted to a string) to the end of another string. Is that it?

Comment: Hi Ken  yes something like that  Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this within Visual Studio? If not, then why the [tag:visual-studio] tag?

Comment: Hi Zev Im doing it in MS access VBA however the admin asked me to select more than one tag for my question that why I put visual_studio thanks

Comment: *can you help me to know the MS access VBA code* Nope, please, post what have you tried, and where are you stuck on your code.

Answer (score 0):

(I am assuming the commas are not part of your data.)

I would suggest that you create a dummy table with numbers from `0` to the maximum possible value in `Range_upper`. You'd probably want to use VBA for that.

Then you can write the following SQL (assuming the `Dummy` table has a `Num` field):

```
SELECT Phone_number_main, Phone_number_main & Dummy.Num AS Phone_number_extention
INTO Table2
FROM Table1, Dummy
WHERE Dummy.Num BETWEEN Table1.Range_lower AND Table1.Range_upper
```

Running this query will recreate `Table2` each time.

Comment: You will need to format the extension in case those were, say, (0)5 to 15.

Comment: @Gustav Maybe, but the OP's data might imply that shorter phone numbers get more digits in the extension.

Comment: @Zev yes the commas are not part of the data.

Comment: @Zev at the start the table2 will be empty and no data and then the script should fill it with related extension numbers for each main number based on the defined lower and upper extension.

Comment: @Yasir You don't need a script (presumably you mean a program written in VBA). You can save this query and run it as needed, Alternatively, you could have VBA run this query, either the saved version, or the direct SQL.